# Calling a method when scroll starts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that uses scroll events. When the scroll event is called it basically runs the handler as expected. However I need to be able to call a method once when the scroll events begin to fire. I understand the idea of a debounce method which would fire when the scroll stops, but I need to find a way to fire once when scrolling begins. (For sure NO jQuery can be used).

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);

    this.setState({
        // sets some state which is compared in a shouldComponentUpdate
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState);
}
```

The handler seen below runs some code:

```
onScroll() {
    this.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    this.update();
}
```

But I need a function that runs once:

```
scrollStart() {

}
```

I would love to say I have tried something but unfortunately I have no ideas. Any assist would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real scrolling state in the browser; the scroll event happens, and then it's over.

You could e.g. create a new timeout each time the user scrolls and set your own scrolling state to false if the user hasn't scrolled until the timeout function is run.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  timeout = null;
  state = { isScrolling: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  }

  onScroll = () => {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    const { isScrolling } = this.state;

    if (!isScrolling) {
      this.setState({ isScrolling: true });
    }

    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ isScrolling: false });
    }, 200);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 1000,
          background: this.state.isScrolling ? "green" : "red"
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. I appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the scrollStart() function to only fire once, the very first time a user scrolls? If do, this could be easily accomplished with a scrollStarted variable. `if (scrollStarted == false) { scrollStarted = true; scrollStart(); }`.

I can imagine a similar scenario if you want the function to fire when a user starts scrolling from the top (it can fire again if the user returns to the top). Just replace `(scrollStarted == false)` with `scrollTop == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `scrollstart` event in javascript, however you *can* register pointer events on the parent element and scroll events on the target element.

Then, for example, in the `pointerdown` callback reset a variable that gets set when scrolling starts.

If you want you can even dispatch a custom "scrollstart" event on the target when the scroll event is triggered and `var scrolling` is not set.

For `document.body` you can listen for pointer ( or touch or mouse ) events on `window`.

Answer (score -1):

For this you could define a static variable and when the scroll starts, put `true` in the variable and enter a `while` that keeps checking if the scrool continues. Using this logic, you may be able to do something.

Comment: Not while, while blocks all other code on the page. Use setInterval instead.